# I used google apps. A new email account created in webhosting/cpanel can not received emails

Tags: google, webmail, application

try to find a post that similar to my question but it seem there is none of them is answering my question.

I have 5 email user accounts in google apps (it is running well till now),  because of it went to commercial so decided to keep using the google apps but i will not create a new email account using google apps anymore. so I created a new email account in cpanel of my webhosting and used roundcube for webmail server. the problem was i can still use the new email account for sending an email but I can not received any email from outsites. there always a massages like this below:

Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
webmaster@terataicapitalindonesia.com
Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain terataicapitalindonesia.com by aspmx.l.google.com. [2607:f8b0:4003:c01::1b].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 c1si13498081oeq.10 - gsmtp

please what should i do? is it the MX record or something should be adjust?
please help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cpanel and not a direct admin question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mail is being handled by Gmail. Adding a webmail account in Cpanel won't do anything, as your MX records are sending all e-mails to Gmail for handling. Gmail accurately reports that the account doesn't exist.

You can't split services like this with e-mail. You'll need to pick one service or the other for the domain's e-mail.

Comment: thank you for quick your answer respons, so this is mean that i have to choose one of the options? google apps or webmail?can i we do something with the mx?

Comment: You can't do split delivery with MX records, no. You need to pick either Google Apps or Cpanel's mail, or run them on different subdomains or something.